# Skipping every other array element

Tags: smalltalk, squeak

So Im trying to skip past every other element and enter them into a collection. I am then converting the collection back to an array and trying to return it. Im not sure whats wrong though.

```
altElement

    | newColl x y |
    newColl:= OrderedCollection new.

          x := 1.
          [x <= self size ] whileTrue: [x := x + 2 |
        newColl add: (self at: x)].

        y:= newColl asArray.

        ^y
```

Comment: The part of the block between **[** and **|** is reserved for arguments being passed into the block. Additionally, the `whileTrue:` message it expects a block that takes no arguments. The expression `x := x + 2` belongs on the right side of the **|**. Next, think about the order of which you are using **x** as an index and the incrementing of **x**. Is it possible that **x** will exceed the size of your collection before the message `self at: x`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another, more cross dialect variant, is to remember that intervals are collections too (I find this more *functional* as well).

```
| sequence |
sequence = #('I' 'invented' 'the' 'term' 'Object' 'Oriented' 'Programming' 'and' 'this' 'is' 'not' 'it').
(1 to: sequence size by: 2) collect: [:n | sequence at: n]
```

will return:

```
#('I' 'the' 'Object' 'Programming' 'this' 'not')
```

But can be easily changed to return

```
#('invented' 'term' 'Oriented' 'and' 'is' 'it')
```

by simply swapping the leading `1` for a `2`. What's nice though, is that you can slice it any way you want. If your dialect has a pairsCollect:, you can only use it for adjacent items. You can't get every third word starting two from the back in backwards order:

```
(sequence size - 1 to: 1 by: -3) collect: [:n | sequence at: n]
"returns"
#('not' 'and' 'Object' 'invented')
```

I find that using the sequence as a slice iterator to `collect:` is a far more useful and general pattern to use.

Answer (score 4):

You probably want `#pairsDo:` or even `#pairsCollect:`.

```
#(1 2 3 4 5 6 7) pairsCollect: [:a :b | b]. "=> #(2 4 6)"
```